# How to properly exec() a coroutine

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm writing a Discord bot, and I'm having trouble testing an async function. I want to test it by using `exec()`, but I can't seem to call the function properly.

I've tried exec()-ing the function both with and without an await. I've looked at the [API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#what-is-a-coroutine), but that hasn't given me much insight into my problem. Using `eval()`, it returns the coroutine object, but doesn't execute it.

The exec() is done by processing the message with an async function

```
async def f(message)
    #other stuff
    ...
    ...
    exec(strip2(message.content, "exec"))
    return #exec doesn't return anything, so we return to not send an empty message
```

The async function looks something like this:

```
async def move_message(message_id, old_channel, new_channel):
    """
    check the 20 latest messages in old_channel, and if
    one of them matches the id, move it to new_channel
    """
    print("ok")
    async for message in old_channel.history(limit=20):
        #do stuff
        ...
    print("good!")
```

Without the await, it gives this error: `...\commands.py:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'move_message' was never awaited` 
With the await, it gives me a `SyntaxError`:

```
 File "<string>", line 1
    await move_message(message, message.channel, "admin-test-playground")
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I want the function to be executed properly, at least printing something. But neither "ok" nor "good!" prints with what I have now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`async` and `await` have special syntax. `await expr` only parses correctly within an `async def` context. So `exec("await function()")` will raise a `SyntaxError` since `exec` operates by parsing a statement and running it, so it doesn't respect the event loop.

Therefore, you cannot use `exec` in async code to call async functions. This makes sense once you understand more of how async functions work under the hood, since `await` changes the behavior of the code more than a function call would.

However, if you switch to using `eval`, the code you had before should instead return the coroutine object you are calling. Since coroutine objects are awaitable, you can then use this as you were intending with `exec`.

So you should be able to do something like

```py
def f(message):
    await eval(message.lstrip('exec '))
```

and have it work correctly.

Comment: I tried using `eval`, but that sends that same syntax error as a message. "_invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)_"

Comment: You would need to remove the `await` from the beginning of the line

Comment: So something like `eval(move_message(1, "bot-playground",  "admin-test-playground"))`? I tried that before, and it returns the coroutine object, but doesn't execute. I'll update the question to include that I've tried that.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. You have the coroutine object, and you need to await on it. So it would be like `await eval('move_message(1, "bot-playground", "admin-test-playground")')`.